# IBM DB2 error sql code-724 & sql state 54038

Tags: db2, db2-express-c

I was trying to insert some sample data to the table but the db2 command line processor return this message "DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0723N  An error occurred in a triggered SQL statement in trigger
"EDWIN.CALLCQ".  Information returned for the error includes `SQLCODE "-724"`,
`SQLSTATE "54038"` and message tokens "EDWIN.CHKQUANTITY|PROCEDURE ".
SQLSTATE=09000"

Here is my procedure

```
create procedure chkQuantity (Cart_ID int,Food_ID int, Food_Quantity int)begin declare c cursor with return for select sum(Food_Quantity) from Cart_details group by Cart_ID;open c; If(Food_Quantity <= 10)then insert into cart_details(Cart_ID,Food_ID,Food_Quantity) values (Cart_ID , Food_ID ,Food_Quantity);Else signal sqlstate'45000' set message_text = '1 Cart Maximum order only 10 food Quantity' ;delete from cart_details where cart_details_id=cart_details_id; end if;close c; end
```

trigger

```
create trigger callCQ after insert on cart_details referencing new as N for each row mode db2sql call chkQuantity(N.Cart_ID, N.Food_ID, N.Food_Quantity)
```

table

```
create table Cart_Details(Cart_Details_ID int not null primary key ,Cart_ID int , Foreign Key(Cart_ID) references Cart,Food_ID int,foreign key(Food_ID) references Food, Food_quantity int check(food_quantity <= 10))
```

Comment: It would be useful to include the actual error message instead of just the error codes that it includes.

Comment: As for your procedure logic. You should be aware of the following. Using a cursor without `fetch` is useless: you can't use its result with just open / close statements.  You delete all rows in the table with the  `delete from cart_details where cart_details_id=cart_details_id` statement, since if your column and parameter names are equal, then such a name is treated as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the [SQL0724N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic3.html#sql0724n) message clearly states that:

> **SQL0724N**
>    The activation of *object-name* of type *object-type* would
>   exceed the maximum level of indirect SQL cascading.
>
> **Explanation**
>   Cascading of indirect SQL occurs when a trigger activates another
>   trigger (possibly through referential constraint delete rules) or a
>   routine, containing SQL, invokes another routine. The depth of this
>   cascading is limited to 16 for triggers and 64 for routines. Note that
>   recursive situations where a trigger includes a triggered SQL
>   statement that directly or indirectly causes the same trigger to be
>   activated, or where a routine directly or indirectly invokes itself,
>   is a form of cascading that is very likely to cause this error if
>   there are no conditions to prevent cascading from exceeding the limit.
>   The object-type is one of TRIGGER, FUNCTION, METHOD, or PROCEDURE. The
>   object-name specified is one of the objects that would have been
>   activated at the seventeenth level of cascading.
>
> **User response**
>   Start with the objects that are activated or invoked by the statement that
>   received this error. If any of these objects are recursive, ensure
>   that there is some condition that prevents the object from being
>   activated or invoked more than the limit allows. If this is not the
>   cause of the problem, follow the chain of objects that are activated
>   or invoked to determine the chain that exceeds the cascading limit.

You call a routine inserting a row into a table in the `after insert` trigger. This leads to recursive calls of this trigger exceeding the allowed number of cascading calls.

Comment: I found a fix to it just remove the sum from the procedure and change it to count it work fine